# What do "leaps of faith" and "get the best of somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

I came across these two phrases when reading *The Da Vinci Code*.

> Why not-if we're assuming the Church was able to uncover the identities of the Priory members, then certainly they could have learned of their plans. And even if they don't have the exact date, their superstitions may be **getting the best of them**.

---

> "Here is perhaps the best-known tome," Teabing said, pulling a tattered hardcover from the stack and handing it to her. The cover read:
>
> HOLY BLOOD, HOLY GRAIL
>   The Acclaimed International Bestseller
>
> Sophie glanced up. "An international bestseller? I've never heard of it."
>   "You were young. This caused quite a stir back in the nineteen eighties. To my taste, the authors made some dubious **leaps of faith** in their analysis, but their fundamental premise is sound, and to their credit, they finally brought the idea of Christ's bloodline into the mainstream".

I looked up these terms, but I still don't understand their contextual meanings.

What do they mean in their respective contexts?

Comment: To my BrE ear, *[bad thing] got the **best** of [someone]* sounds slightly odd. I'm much more accustomed to hearing that something *got the **better** of them*. All it means is they were ***bested** by* (succumbed to) their superstitions. And making a *leap of faith* just means adopting a position based on belief/faith/prejudice rather than evidence/reason.

Comment: Dan Brown (your author) is widely recognized to mangle language. Be careful with reading him.

Comment: @medica Oi, [don’t make fun of renowned Dan Brown](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/10049454/Dont-make-fun-of-renowned-Dan-Brown.html).

Answer (score 2):

Two questions, two answers.

**First answer:**

"*[**get the best**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/best?s=t)*" is probably connected to the verbal use of ***BEST***

> ***Best*** vt vt (documented first use 1830) to get the better of; defeat; beat; overcome:
>
> He easily *bested* his opponent in hand-to-hand combat.
>
> She bested me in the argument.

"...their superstitions ***may be getting the best*** of them.", comfortably yields:

> ...their superstitions may be ***DEFEATING*** them.
>
> OR
>   ...their superstitions may be ***BEATING*** them
>
> OR ...their superstitions may be ***OVERCOMING*** them.

**Second answer:**

[***Leap of faith***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/leap+of+faith) probably traces back to Soren Kierkegaard's "leap **to** faith" which does not necessarily coincide with the current definition:

> ***leap of faith***, an act or instance of accepting or trusting in something that cannot readily be seen or proved.
>
> "To assume that we can succeed where everyone else failed requires a
>   giant *leap of faith*."

Rearranging some phrases for the sake of clarity, "...the authors made some dubious leaps of faith in their analysis," comfortably yields:

> ...in their analysis, the authors dubious[ly] ***accepted things that
>   cannot be readily seen or proved***,"

Answer (score 1):

For AmE, we do say getting the ***best*** rather than the BrE ***better***, which I had never thought of as problematic until FumbleFinger's quote.  This particular use of *getting the best of them* sounds a little weird to me.

For *leap of faith*, it's a phrase often associated with Kierkegaard (who does use the phrase, though as a Kierkegaard scholar I think the popular usage is a misunderstanding). I would define the popular expression slightly differently than FumbleFingers does in his quote, viz., a leap of faith is when you **skip** steps in your argumentation or reasoning to reach your conclusion, rather than when you *adopt a position based on belief/faith/prejudice instead of reason/evidence.*

E.g.,

```
Given premise: If it rains, then he will come for me.

Leap: I just know it will rain

Enabling the conclusion: He will come for me.
```

rather than simply *he will come for me* as a leap.

And I think the emphasis on **skipping** is borne out in your quotation. Note the presence of an initial premise and a belief that there is a sound chain of reasoning which could yield the conclusion.

---

For Kierkegaard himself, this is not what *leap of faith* meant. Instead, it was that until you have taken up faith, you cannot understand the argument. In other words, it was a claim about hermeneutics and epistemic closure. Probably, the easiest species to understand that he mentions is love -- sometimes you cannot see what is lovable in someone until you are already loving them.

Comment: Wikipedia claims (and I don't know enough about it to say one way or the other) that though the phrase is often associated with Kierkegaard, he didn't actually use it: he used ‘leap _to_ faith’, which apparently has quite different psychological connotations. I rather thought (and Wikipedia seems to confirm) that he wrote in Danish, which—quite interestingly—has no such phrase as ‘leap of faith’. I'm not even sure how I'd translate it into Danish, truth be told.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not fluent in Danish, but the choice of preposition seems minor and unimportant to me. Leap of faith sometimes shows up in the Kgd literature (mostly to show it is wrong or in some rather poor early articles). But my claim isn't the positive claim that he uses *leap of faith* but rather that what he's talking about that gets called *leap of faith* is something else.

Answer (score 0):

"Getting the best" of someone is defeating them.  If your superstitions get the best of you that means that they manage to defeat your ability to think rationally.

A "leap of faith" is accepting something as true/valid/meaningful without a significant amount of proof/evidence.  Sometimes this just means trusting someone, and sometimes it means going off ones nut, particularly about religion.